# Matplotlib fill_between shows a sliver of white when filing from zero

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = np.cos(x)

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

ax.plot(x, y, c='black', linewidth=1) 
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=(x >= 0) & (x < np.pi), color='gray')

ax.set_xbound(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi)
ax.set_ybound(-3, 3)

f.suptitle("Area under a cosine function", size='x-large', weight='bold')
f.show()
```

There is just a tiny sliver of white showing just right of the x=0 position. Is this my fault in calculation or some kind of issue with matplotlib? I assume by having x>=0 in the where parameter I'm fine, but I don't see what else I can adjust.
Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly floating point round off.  Try x > -1e-15

Comment: Just tried up to -1e-30; still a sliver (seems to be unchanged by visual inspection) of white left....

Comment: @Five9 note that `|-1e-30| < |-1e-15|` I just played around and found that the cutoff point for this working is around -1e-12 so i'd use `-1e-10`. Alternatively using `x = np.linspace` with 500 or so points also works well

Comment: Just tried to -1e-10 and it worked, thanks!
Want to repost as answer?